# Finite representation type of certain triangular matrix ring

Tags: representation-theory

Given a field $k$, let $\Lambda=k[X]/(X^n)$ be a local $k$-algebra with $n\geq 3$. Let $T_2(\Lambda)$ be the following triangular matrix ring:

\begin{equation}
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \Lambda & 0\\
    \Lambda & \Lambda\\
  \end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}.

Is $T_2(\Lambda)$ of finite representation type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra $T_2(\Lambda)$ is representation finite if and only if $n\le3$.

- $T_2(\Lambda)$ is representation finite if and only if the Auslander algebra of $\Lambda$ is representation finite. (Theorem 1.1 in *Auslander, Reiten: On the representation type of triangular matrix rings. J. London Math. Soc. (2) 12 (1975/76), no. 3, 371–382.* )
- The Auslander algebra of $\Lambda$ is representation finite if and only if $n\le3$. (This follows from Theorem 2.1 in *Drozd, Mazorchuk: Representation type of ${}^{\infty}_{\lambda}\mathscr{H}^{1}_{\mu}$. Q. J. Math. 57 (2006), no. 3, 319–338.*, but there is probably an easier reference somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.